# Error: Item (Magento\Framework\DataObject) with the same ID "50" already exists

Tags: magento2

After running `catalog:images:resize` I got the following error:

`php magento catalog:images:resize`

> ...........Item (Magento\Framework\DataObject) with the same ID "50"
>   already exists.

Does anybody have any idea what would the issue be and where to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: (I'm running Magento version 2.0.12)

Comment: do you have any third-party modules?

Comment: I have 'Magento 2 Blog Extension' installed.

Comment: try to disable third-party extensions and re-run console command after clearing caches.

Comment: I disabled it and flushed cache and still get the same error.